# C : Unix SDL2 library : undefined reference, issue in the Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, sdl

I'm looking to make a Makefile that can compile a C program on Unix (Ubuntu). That Makefile should include the SDL library (2.0), as well as SDL_image.

So here's my current Makefile :

```
CC = gcc
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
EXEC = main

LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs` -L/usr/lib -lSDL2_image
CCFLAGS = `sdl2-config --cflags` -I/usr/include/SDL_image.h

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXEC)
```

And here's my current code (minimal code just to test the Makefile):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("Initialization error: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640, 480,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

So when I write the command : make

I get errors on all of the SDL functions.
Here's an example : undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

I have tried many things (such as different paths for the Include and Link in the Makefile), but nothing seems to work.

So my question is : How can I solve theses undefined references to SDL2 functions ?

Comment: I'm not a unix/makefile guy, but I see `-lSDL2_image` and not `-lSDL` on your linker line?

Comment: @wizebin: That's what `\`sdl-2config --libs\`` does.

Comment: Ah, well TIL! I'm used to being pampered by my IDE- which needs the `-lSDL` flag.

Comment: in `gcc`, the linker processes the parameters in the order listed on the command line.   and for this line: `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@` the libraries are listed before everything else, so when the libraries are processed there are no unresolved references to fix.  The correct way to write the line is: `$(CC)  $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)`  Note: `$^` so the whole list of prerequisites are included, not just the first prerequisite.

Comment: when defining a macro for the name of an executable, like: `CC := gcc`,  (`:=` so only evaluated once)  the idea is to pin point which `gcc` to execute rather than accepting which ever one is found first via the `PATH` environment variable.  so such `make` lines should be: `CC := /usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying linker flags in the wrong order.

This is wrong:

```
LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs` -L/usr/lib -lSDL2_image
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This is correct:

```
LIBS = `sdl2-config --libs` -L/usr/lib -lSDL2_image
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

With GNU Binutils, the order of libraries is important.  Libraries must come after the objects which have undefined references to symbols in those libraries.  It sucks, it's stupid, but it's the way GNU Binutils works and you're stuck with it.

### Other fixes

- You want `$^` instead of `$<`, because `$<` is only the *first* dependency.
- Probably best to use `pkg-config` which can find SDL2_image for you:

  ```
  LIBS = `pkg-config --libs sdl2 SDL2_image`
  ```
- You probably want `:=` not `=` when you invoke shell programs, this will expand the variable once, instead of every time it is used:

  ```
  LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs sdl2 SDL2_image)
  CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags sdl2 SDL2_image)
  ```

### Full example

Here is a cleaned up example, close to how I would write it:

```
# use := not =
# convention: objects, exec are lower-case because they're private
objects := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags sdl2 SDL2_image)
LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs sdl2 SDL2_image)

# Don't define CC, because the default (cc) is fine
# It's probably linked to gcc on your system anyway

# = or := doesn't matter here
exec = main

# must use = here
depflags = -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) -MMD -MP
-include $(wildcard *.d)

$(exec): $(objects)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(depflags) -c $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d $(exec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You inverted some compiler/linker options:

```
# linker options
LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs` -I/usr/include/SDL_image.h
# compiler options
CCFLAGS = `sdl2-config --cflags` -L/usr/lib -lSDL2_image
```

It should be:

```
# linker options
LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs` -L/usr/lib -lSDL2_image
# compiler options
CCFLAGS = `sdl2-config --cflags` -I/usr/include
```

Details:

```
-L Is to indicate to the linker where to find .so files
-l Is to link to a given library
-I Is to indicate to the compiler where to find .h files
```

Comment: Yes It's true I inverted them! Thank you

Comment: @Caro: Did you `make clean` after you changed your makefile?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes I just did and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](//gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Linking a single object file
>
> `n` is made automatically from `n.o` by running the linker (usually called
>   `ld`) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is:
>
> ```
> $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
> ```

and [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](//gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables):

> LDFLAGS
>
> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker,
>   `ld`, such as `-L`. Libraries (`-lfoo`) should be added to the LDLIBS variable
>   instead.

So in this case `-lSDL2_image` should be set or added to LDLIBS, not LDFLAGS.